# How can I parse this type of JSON [PHP]

Tags: php, json

this is the JSON below I want to parse

`{"events": [{"eventId": 2, "payload": {"chat": {"chatId": "683473108@chat.agent", "title": "TrojanTest", "type": "group"}, "from": {"firstName": "Khan", "nick": "Mr.Tr0J4n", "userId": "751401693"}, "msgId": "6895591502924218369", "text": "524545", "timestamp": 1605505008}, "type": "newMessage"}], "ok": true}`
I want to parse `msgId` and `chatId` from this JSON.

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: `$parsedJSON = json_decode($JSON);` Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

decode json string to array:

```
$jsonString = '{"events": [{"eventId": 2, "payload": {"chat": {"chatId": "683473108@chat.agent", "title": "TrojanTest", "type": "group"}, "from": {"firstName": "Khan", "nick": "Mr.Tr0J4n", "userId": "751401693"}, "msgId": "6895591502924218369", "text": "524545", "timestamp": 1605505008}, "type": "newMessage"}], "ok": true}';

$arr = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

fetch from array:

```
$chatId = $arr['events'][0]['payload']['chat']['chatId'];
$msgId = $arr['events'][0]['payload']['msgId'];
var_dump($chatId);
var_dump($msgId);
```

the result will be:

```
string(20) "683473108@chat.agent"
string(19) "6895591502924218369"
```